# Change Safari microphone input device to be blackhole or soundflower

Tags: macos, safari, audio, monterey, microphone

I want to change Safari input device from built-in microphone to Blackhole 2ch.

I tried to do this by choosing Blackhole as the Input device system-wide in System Preferences.

The input device is working, in every other app I can use it as the input device and hear that it records properly, in System Preferences the volume monitor flickers correctly.

However, Safari always just records silence. I've tested with two websites: Whatsapp and https://online-voice-recorder.com

It just records silence, except a single tiny blip of the audio I am routing through blackhole.... sometimes.

What's going on with Safari? How can I route songs of my choosing into Safari as if it were through the microphone?

Comment: It might be more helpful if you'd also add a URL that you're having an issue with in Safari. That way we would have something to test against that's not working for you.

Comment: @user3439894 any microphone input.

Comment: What are your settings at Safari > Preferences > Websites > Microphone?

Comment: @user3439894 ask

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, which **sound input device** is used is controlled by the **OS** in **System Preferences** > **Sound** > **Input** (*as shown in the second image below*) and some, but not all, apps one can choose a **sound input device** other than the one set for the **OS**. For example, in **Audacity** you can select other than the one set for the **OS**.

However, I am not aware of a built-in preference in **Safari** that lets one choose a **sound input device**. There is a microphone setting in **Safari**, but it doesn't offer control over which **sound input device** to use.

Have a look in: **Safari** > **Preferences** > **Websites** > **Microphone**

[image]

[image]

Comment: I guess it's impossible then.